# getting column name using iloc in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Is there a way to get the column name as a value using *iloc* or other functions?

i have a for loop here:

```
for i in range(0,18):
    coef, pval = pearsonr(x.iloc[:,i],y)
    print('pval of ',x.iloc[?,i], ' and allStar: ', pval)
```

where i want to print 'pval of  *column_name*  and allStar:  *pval*'

is there a value I can replace *?* with so that it fetches the column name for each of the columns? Or I have to use another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer for your direct question is to use [`x.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html).

```py
for i in range(0,18):
    coef, pval = pearsonr(x.iloc[:,i],y)
    print('pval of ',x.columns[i], ' and allStar: ', pval)
```

A cleaner approach would be to simply iterate over the columns:

```py
for c in x.columns:
    coef, pval = pearsonr(x[c], y)
    print('pval of ',c, ' and allStar: ', pval)
```

---

Bonus notes (mainly to avoid the loop...):

- To get the **correlation coefficients** (and not the **pvalues** just yet) of each column with `y`, you can simply use [`corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html):

```py
r = x.corrwith(pd.Series(y), axis=0)
```

- To obtain the **pvalues** that correspond to those Pearson coefficients, you can simply calculate them directly, [as](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) follows:

```py
dist = scipy.stats.beta(n/2 - 1, n/2 - 1, loc=-1, scale=2)  # n == len(y)
p = 2*dist.cdf(-abs(r))  # <= the pvalues!
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus notes Yaniv! very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is Your dataframe try converting column name to column index:

```
col_idx = x.columns.get_loc('column_name')
```

Now this index can be passed to `iloc` method.